# Converting the placeholder value to required format in the SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I am using db2 database. I have to query a table called "sample" which has one of its column `CRDATTIM` defined as `TIMESTAMP`.

I am querying the table from java using place holders like this:

```
select * from sample where crdattim=? and recordcd='C';
```

The values of the CRDATTIM fields are of the below TIMESTAMP format.

```
 CRDATTIM                                   RECORDCD 

2014-08-08 12:12:39.621060                  O   
2014-08-27 07:01:46.814080                  T   
2014-08-27 06:41:47.404080                  T   
2014-08-27 07:14:47.871080                  T   
2014-08-28 02:23:50.390080                  T   
2014-08-28 06:27:58.298080                  T   
2014-09-02 08:57:37.607080                  T
```

From java end, the value of `CRDATTIM` is passed in slightly different format.i.e for example `2014-08-08-12.12.39.621060` instead of `2014-08-08 12:12:39.621060`. I don't convert to required format `2014-08-08-12.12.39.621060` at java end, but rather I want to convert it at the database end.

I tried with the following query, but didn't worked.

```
select * from sample where VARCHAR_FORMAT(crdattim,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')=? and recordcd='C';
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: if `crdattim` is a datetime type, you should only put a java.sql.Timestamp as parameter

Comment: Thanks for the response. crdattim  is of  Timestamp  type in the table.The same column is defined as `Char` in oracle.  I am developing a utility which is common for all the databases. I am not interested to handle these kind of checks whether it is char or timestamp in the java code. I want to handle it in the sql queries. Is there any way? something like casting or using other functions of database.

Comment: Sonds like you want to reinvent the wheel (OR-Mapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
select * from sample where VARCHAR_FORMAT(crdattim,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6')=? and recordcd='C';
```

or

```
  select * from sample where to_char(crdattim,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6')=? and recordcd='C';
```

Comment: what is the error ? I checked in my local it got worked

Comment: against db2 database?